# Ionic call to another method in same controller gets undefined?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-change

I have simple ionic template like this:

```
    <ion-item class="range range-calm">Shift {{shiftval}}: 
        <input ng-change="shiftChange()" type="range" ng-model="shiftval" min="1" max="25">
    </ion-item>
        <span class="input-label">In</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="decripted" id="dec" ng-change="change()" />
    </label>
        <span class="input-label">Out</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="encripted" />
    </label>
```

with controller logic like this:

```
.controller('mylog', function($scope) {
    var shiftval = ( typeof shiftval === 'undefined' ) ? 13 : shiftval;
    $scope.change = function(){
        this.decripted = this.decripted.toUpperCase();
        this.encripted = cezarCipher(this.decripted, shiftval);
    };
    $scope.shiftChange = function(){
        shiftval = this.shiftval;
        $scope.change();
    };
})
```

on the last line where I try to call `$scope.change();` simply to trigger event and re-render text again I get error like this:

`Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined` on the line .toUpperCase() in that fn.

If anyone has idea how to overcome this, I would be very thankfull!

Comment: you need to use $scope.decripted. this.decripted is undefined

Comment: tried that, but that fails too

Answer (score 1):

try giving `$scope.decripted` an initial value, it is probably hasn't been set the first time the `$scope.change` function is fired in the controller.

Since decripted is undefined, trying to call the function `toUpperCase()` on it will trigger an error, since it is not a string.

Comment: thanks, but I console.log'ed it and it has value when Im in change() fn, but not when I'm calling it from shiftChange(), can you post the code where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parameter as `ng-model` in your `function`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="decripted" id="dec" ng-change="change(decripted)" />
```

and your `controller` like this

```
$scope.change = function(decripted){
   var decripted = decripted.toUpperCase();
   encripted = cezarCipher(decripted, shiftval);
};
```